# Problems with catch in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with the catch command. I have the following script I'm trying to process:

```
Try
{
    Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDomain.Dom" -Credential $DomainCred -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
}

Catch [System.InvalidOperationException]
{
    "Your computer is unable to contact the domain"
}
```

Every time I run this though I am not getting anything in the catch block. Here is the error reported that I get from the script:

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.InvalidOperationException: This command cannot be executed on target computer('') due to following error: The specified domain either does not exist or could not
                        be contacted.
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MYPC:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

Any ideas?

---

A working solution (thanks to PK and Patrick for their combined contributions):

```
Try
{
    Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDomain.Dom" -Credential $DomainCred -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
}

Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
{
    "Your computer is unable to contact the domain"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try catching `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` instead of `System.InvalidOperationException`.

```
Try
{
    Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDomain.Dom" -Credential $DomainCred
}

Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
{
    'Error: {0}' -f $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I replaced it with System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException but I still got the same problem.  I even tried taking out any error and using just Catch but the problem persists.

Comment: You can't get in the Catch block at all?  Try this and tell me what the output is : Try
{
 throw
}
Catch
{
 $_.Exception.GetType() | select FullName
}

Answer (score 2):

Add "-ErrorActionPreference Stop" to your cmdlet.

For instance,

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDomain.Dom" -Credential $DomainCred -EA Stop
```

There does seem to be a few inconsistencies with the ways that different cmdlets process errors, especially those "add-on" cmdlets like the Active Directory ones. However, I think the basic idea is that PowerShell catch only catches terminating errors, of which your exception above isn't by default. So by using `-EA Stop` you're forcing it be a terminating error, which triggers the catch block.

Here's Ed Wilson on the subject: *[Write PowerShell Functions That Accept Pipelined Input](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx)*

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work:

```
Try
{
    Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDomain.Dom" -Credential $DomainCred -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
}

Catch
{
    "Your computer is unable to contact the domain"
}
```

`-PassThru` on the `Add-Computer` command returns the results of the command to the shell.

`-ErrorAction Stop` tells PowerShell to stop when it encounters an error; this suppresses the error output you were seeing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FullName                                                                                                                                                                   
--------                                                                                                                                                                   
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException                                                                                                                              
The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a user-specified "f
ormat-list" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `-Passthru` on it allowed it to catch the error.